# Windows NFS share access from Linux unjoined domain computer with AD username using NIS

Tags: linux, windows, permissions, nfs

I have Linux clients using AD username/password using NIS and we have NIS Domain and UID and GID are already present in the AD. We used to have Windows 2003 NFS share and it used to work fine with permissions but now we moved to Windows 2019 and the same mapping is not available in Windows 2019.

Microsoft used to have User Name Mapping in Win 2003 NFS server which is depreciated now. In User Name Mapping, You can Group maps the Windows group to Unix Group. This helps in accessing the share that is located on Windows NFS from Linux with right permission. Now this is not available in new version like 2016 and 2019.

What is the way to translate the Unix group id to Windows ID?

A similar post is here but not sure what format to use to match the group membership for Windows AD group and Unix Group.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66923788/windows-server-2019-server-for-nfs-uid-gid-mapping-with-auth-sys?rq=1

I have tried with local file as well but may be I am doing something wrong.

We are looking for solution that Linux users that are using their AD username can access the NFS share via NIS.

Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same problem and this is the best I have found on the subject which should answer your quesiton.

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/070565a8-b031-4f16-a9ee-1319f07f42cf/how-to-mount-nfs-share-on-windows-10-pro-and-use-unix-attributes-from-active-directory-for?forum=winserverDS

Seems like you would need to manually enter UID and GID for every AD user which is unreasonable.

We are going to be using SMB instead.

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser! Please do not post link only answers as the linked site might change, rendering your answer useless. Instead please quote the most important parts and provide the link for reference only.